# Искажение русского текста в $_GET, $_POST?

Tags: массивы, ajax, кодировка, php

Имеется AJAX, посылает PHP данные в виде строки(русский текст);

На стороне PHP делаю следующее:

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['data'])) {
    echo $_POST['data']; die(); // Вот здесь Ð¾Ð»ÐºÐ½
    echo json_encode(array('data' => $_POST['data'])); die(); 
}
```

Там где первый *echo* - выводит русский текст как крокодил...
Если его убрать и вызвать *json_encode*, то бишь проверить текст в *callback success ajax*, то туда он приходит "здоровый".

Пример вызывающего AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
                url: url,
                type : 'post',
                dataType    : 'text',
                data: { term : 'ОЛОЛО' },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data); // Выводит ОЛОЛО
                    response($.map(data.res, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name,
                            value: item.id,
                        };
                    }));

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все файлы исходных кодов должны быть в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM. База данных (если оттуда приходить будет) должна быть в utf8-general-ci.